# Datepicker that can also select whole week

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is it possible that jQuery's datepicker have an option that will give ability to select single day (like it have) but **also** to select whole week?

I need both of those two in same datepicker...

Tnx in adv!

Comment: This is a fairly specific request, good luck finding a calendar component that can do it. Can't you just add a checkbox to the form that says "all week" and show which days those are somewhere else in the UI?

Comment: Why don't you make 2 radio buttons, one for `Day ` and another for `Week `.  Have `StartDate ` and `EndDate ` fields. If the user has `Day ` selected, auto populate `EndDate ` with `StartDate `. If `Week ` is selected, auto populate `EndDate ` with `StartDate + 7 days `. Simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the two links below, they both work with jQuery UI:

- [Week picker using jQuery UI Datepicker](http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/week-picker-using-jquery-ui-datepicker)
- [Date Range Picker using jQuery UI 1.7 and jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Hopefully, it will help you get going.